# Linux - How to solve 'Word too long.' in SUSE10 OS

Tags: linux, shell, unix, operating-system, suse

I am using echo cmd to write some text into file, 
The length of the text is around 4403 chars. The cmd works fine in SUSE11 OS. and i get error 'Word too long.' in SUSE10,

any suggestion if the error can be solved ? 
or any other setting to change the length limits?

Comment: What's your command?

Comment: Can you please give us the output of `getconf ARG_MAX`?

Comment: cmd is  : echo 'some_xml_data_of_big_size'  > AC.xml

Comment: getconf ARG_MAX
131072

Comment: Try use `'` other than `"` to quote your text. Meanwhile, why not using a editor?

Comment: It is already used inside shell cmd,, which is working in suse11, same script executed in suse10 started failing.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of parameters (your text) passed to the exec system call (and thus to your echo command) is limited. You can get that length by calling `getconf ARG_MAX`. If you need to exceed this limit, you need to call `echo` multiple times and append the output to the file:

```
echo "Some text" > file
echo "Some more text" >> file
```

Comment: so it is the limitation of OS and cant change the limit ?

Comment: I'm not sure, if this is really the answer to your problem, since your string (size 4403) should fit in your ARG_MAX limit (131072 ).

Comment: Btw. Are you using bash? Bash has a builtin echo, which behaves different from /bin/echo.

Comment: No , in my case echo cmd is called from csh.

Comment: `csh` is often aliased to `tcsh` on various distros. `csh` is more likely to throw the `Word too long` error because the limits are lower.  My guess would be you somehow got switched from `tcsh` to `csh`.